# Find a combinatorial interpretation of $ x_n = x_{n - 2} + x_{n - 3}$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $ x_0 = 3, x_1 = 0, x_2 = 2$ and: $$ x_n = x_{n - 2} + x_{n - 3}$$ 
>   How to find a combinatorial interpretation of this equation?

One idea was to find a number of different tiles of a circle divided on $n$ unit arcs with arcs of lenght $2$ and $3$, but this obviously fails.

Comment: This is [A001608](https://oeis.org/A001608) and there are some suggestions given there (though nothing I'd say was terribly compelling).

Comment: More references and a not particularly funny cartoon are [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerrinSequence.html).

Comment: And [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/PerrinSequence.shtml)  (though no cartoon).

Comment: I haven't a **combinatorial** interpretation. May I ask you why you are interested by this sequence ? Because, with different initial values, it is called the Padovan sequence https://oeis.org/A000931 and has a **geometric** interpretation. See page 70 of this very nice on-line book http://www.m-hikari.com/mccartin-2.pdf

Comment: Yes, of course. For this sequence we have $p\mid x_p$ if $p$  is prime. I want to find a combinatorial argument for this. And thanks you for pointig me to this book. It is marvelous!